# Overriding the operator +

Tags: c++, overriding

I have a question which requires me to override the operator + so that it adds the numeric value of two digits and delivers the digit that we get if we finally apply “modulo 10”. 
(Example ‘5’ + ‘6’ = ‘1’ // 5 + 6 = 11 % 10 = 1)

I have just started learning c++ on my own, a clear explanation would greatly help in my progress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Operator overloading example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199043/c-operator-overloading-example)

Comment: Disagree with that duplicate `<<` and `+` are pretty different. That said, this has to be a dupe of something. While someone hunts up that dupe, Give this a read: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators Particularly about half way down under Binary arithmetic operators. More good reading here: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading

Comment: shall that really be '5' + '6' or "5" + "6"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to overload operator+() for built-in types (`int`, etc).   So, if `a` and `b` are both of type `int` with values `5` and `6` respectively, it is not possible to make `a + b` give a value of `1`.

However, it is possible to do so for user defined types (classes, enums, etc).

For example, with a class type named `MyInt` it is possible to implement an operator+(), as either a member function that accepts one argument, or as a non-member function that accepts two.

Once you can implement an `operator+()`, you can define it to give any result you like.    Your class (which I'm calling `MyInt` for sake of discussion) would probably also need a set of other functions as well (e.g. constructors, other numeric operators).

Note that - although technically possible - it is considered really poor practice to make numeric types that behave counter-intuitively.    Making an numeric type with an addition operator that does something different from addition is counter-intuitive to most people.   Including yourself, if maintaining your code in a few years from now.

Answer (score 0):

For readability/maintainability purposes overloading the operator+() like this, is really bad I think.

Of course you dont want to write

```
(num1 + num2) % 10
```

all the time, so you can have an own function

```
int modulo10AfterAddition (int leftNumber, int rightNumber)
{
    return (leftNumber + rightNumber) % 10;
}
```

Of course, if you create an own class like MyInt, you do modify it accordingly.